# How do i use the load() function on jQuery and style have my style work on it

Tags: html, jquery, css

I wrote a code that will reload a div without refresh the page, like this:

```
$("#content").load(" #content");
```

It works but the CSS I have on its contents changed. Is there a way I could load this and still have my style sheet effective on it?

Answer (score 1):

The `setInterval()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in `milliseconds`).

> Tip: 1000 ms = 1 second.

```
  setInterval(function_name(), 1000);
```